# How to manage all elements in a single event in View (ASP.NET MVC3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, delegates

i need the click tracking module in my asp.net mvc3 application. problem is that How to manage all elements(TextBox, Button, Hyperlink tag, paragraph tag, div tag, ...) in a single event in View (Razor) ASP.NET MVC3.
can i use delegate event method() with jquery for manage all events ???

Below is my "View Page" Html Code:

```
<p>Click this paragraph1.</p>
<p>Click this paragraph2.</p>
<p>Click this paragraph3.</p>
<p>Click this paragraph4.</p>
<div style="background-color:yellow">
heyyy
<button>Click me!</button>
<input type="text">
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/1841626/user1841626">user1841626</a>
</div>
```

Thats is my jquery Script:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").delegate("button","click",function(){
    alert("The button was clicked.");
  })
 $("p").on("click",function(){
  alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
 })
 $("input ").on("click",function(){
  alert("The textBox was clicked.");
 })
 $("a ").on("click",function(){
  alert("The user1841626 was clicked.");
 })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').on('click','button, p, input, a',function(e){
        var tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase(),
            message = '';
        switch(tag){
            case 'a': 
                message = 'user1841626';
                break;
            case 'button': 
                message = 'button';
                break;
            case 'p': 
                message = 'paragraph';
                break;
            case 'input': 
                message = 'textBox';
                break;
        }
        alert('The ' + message + ' was clicked.');
    })
});
```